# TCP - possible for same client-side port to be used for different connections by different applications simlutaneously?

Tags: sockets, tcp, ports

Is it possible in TCP for different processes not sharing the same executable image (so no `fork()` for example) to use a same client-side port on Windows, Linux or OSX? This is specifically related to the socket options `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` set using `setsockopt()` I believe.

As far as I've read, I believe it is possible for the same process/image to do this, but I haven't found information as to multiple processes/images. I would imagine it is theoretically possible since each socket is defined by the 5-valued tuple [IP_PROTO, src_ip:src_port, dst_ip:dst_port]. So I would assume that, as long as multiple TCP connections sharing a client-side port are not made to the same dst_ip:dst_port, this would be theoretically possible.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is not connection-oriented and has no real distinction between client and server, so for UDP this question doesn't make a lot of sense.

For TCP, you can use SO_REUSEADDR to bind mulitple clients to the same port, but why would you want to?  Normally you leave the client unbound before making a connection and let the kernel pick an unused port for you.

Comment: I don't want to, but I need to know if other applications can do this as I depend on whether or not this behaviour is possible.

Comment: So I am to understand that this is indeed possible for different applications?

Comment: Is it *possible*? Yes, if all sockets on the same port use `SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT`. Is it *likely*? No.